# How to add a container around cx-slots

Tags: spartacus-storefront

I'm trying to figure out how to structure my code in a way which i would like it to be for styling purposes but it seems limited i tried using layoutConfig but from my order that doesn't specify where you would like content slots to be rather in which order and what should be rendered for specific template.

I seen that you can use what is called an outletRef which would be perfect for me as i could do something like this

```
<ng-template cxOutletRef="HomePage2018Template">
   <div class="header-container">
      //inject the slots where i want
   </div>
</ng-template>
```

and this would give me the ability to structure the html of my code in any given way but from what i understood with OutletRef you lose the ability to edit the slots in smartedit which would be a problem.

The current implementation i have done is with ConfigModule and i'm mapping my angular components to the typeCode of the components and then in the app.component.html i just have

How can i wrap a container around any given slots?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJ0QQ.png

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom component with your own template, where you can use the cx-page-slot component to place the slots in your own HTML like this:

```html
<div class="stories">
  <cx-page-slot position="Tile1"></cx-page-slot>
  <cx-page-slot position="Tile2"></cx-page-slot>
  <cx-page-slot position="Tile3"></cx-page-slot>
  <cx-page-slot position="Tile4"></cx-page-slot>
  <cx-page-slot position="Tile5"></cx-page-slot>
  <cx-page-slot position="Tile6"></cx-page-slot>
  <cx-page-slot position="Tile7"></cx-page-slot>
  <cx-page-slot position="Tile8"></cx-page-slot>
</div>

<cx-page-slot position="Content"></cx-page-slot>
<cx-page-slot position="Teaser"></cx-page-slot>
<cx-page-slot position="SocialMedia"></cx-page-slot>
```

In your route config you have to use the **CmsPageGuard**, which will fetch the page config from the backend when you hit this route.

e.g.:

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [HomePageComponent],
  imports: [
    PageSlotModule,
    RouterModule.forChild([
      {
        path: '',
        component: HomePageComponent,
        canActivate: [CmsPageGuard],
      },
    ]),
  ],
})
export class HomePageModule {}
```